# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Support for longPress

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium-ios

I am trying to implement swipe functionality with appium but its not working.

```
TouchAction touch = new TouchAction(driver);
touch.longPress(50,199).moveTo(50,300).release().perform();
```

Above code used to perform swipe operation from top to bottom. 
Appium is showing following logs:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Support for longPress(options={"x":50,"y":199})-moveTo(options={"x":50,"y":300})-wait(options={"ms":2000})-release(options={}) gesture is not implemented. Try to use "mobile: *" interface to workaround the issue. Only these gestures are supported:
    doubleTap:      doubletap
        tap(options={"count":2})
    tap:        tap
        tap-release
        press-release
    longPress:      longpress
        longpress-release
        press-wait-release
    drag:       press-wait-moveTo-release
        longpress-moveTo-release
    scroll:         press-moveTo-release
 (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
Command duration or timeout: 0 milliseconds
```

**UPDATE**
The above code works for portrait but it is not applicable for landscape view.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using sleep between the long press and move to so that it if some time is required it will get it.

```
touch.longPress(50,199);
Thread.sleep(3000);
touch.moveTo(50,300).release().perform();
```

**Update** Or you can manually take the coordinates of the place on the screen, where the element was present in landscape mode, while the application is in portrait mode and correlate it.(Take the coordinates of the element in landscape and portrait mode and correlate both).

Comment: Please reply once the code is running or some other work around can be used

Comment: The problem was the application was taking the coordinates from  portrait mode even though it was in landscape mode.